# How to upload a string of JSON data into GCS from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I am getting result set from BigQuery and looping through it so I have string (JSON data) in one of the column that needs to be uploaded to GCS bucket as a file.
File content would be something like

```
{
"name":"sharath",
"country":"India"
}
```

I tried using file.save() method, also `passthroughStream` but nothing happened (not even erroring out)
**file.save() :**

```
for (row of rows) {
  const contents = row.JSON_Content;
  const file = storage.bucket(gcsBucket).file("/" + process.env.FILE_TMP_PATH + fileName + '*.json');
  file.save(contents).then(() => console.messages.push(`file uploaded`));
}
```

**passthroughStream :**

```
for (row of rows) {
const passthroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    passthroughStream.write(contents);
    passthroughStream.end();
    passthroughStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream())
    .on('error', (err) =>{
      throw new Error(`File upload failed with error: ${err.message}`);
    })
    .on('finish', () => {
      // The file upload is complete
    });
}
```

Nothing is working out. These didn't create any file in GCS bucket. I referred [this document](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/HEAD/samples/streamFileUpload.js)
My overall code looks like:

```
//import libraries...
const xxx = { 
myFunction: async () => {
    try{
        ...get data from BigQuery...
        ...loop through resultset...
        ...code not working is illustrated above...
   }catch(err){
        throw new Error('error occured');
   }
}
module.exports = xxx;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so please include them in your question

Comment: No @David, no error.

Answer (score 0):

For save data to file, try to stream it ([createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscreatewritestreampath-options)):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = fs.createWriteStream("/" + process.env.FILE_TMP_PATH + fileName + '*.json', {flags:'a'});
for (row of rows) {
  stream.write(row.JSON_Content);
}
stream.end();
```

Comment: I want to create file in GCS bucket. not in file system

Comment: Maybe, if you separate the workflow into two step, you should have get better solution, get data and crerate it onto file, then upload, instead of stream to upload. It is just an idea.